# PHP clean incoming string with % sign

Tags: php, string, utf-8

I have a query in a php string which i am trying to filter against % signs.
The whole thing is in utf-8.
If the string contains % (for example %acheron) it gets converted to its equivalent entity (in the case I mention it becomes the 'not' sign character which is interpreted by the %ac sequence in the string).
I cant seem to be able to clean the incoming string of this character/
I cant clean the string with a php replace because by the time its in the script it is already "decoded?".

The only way I found that I could figure out was to use rawurlencode and then clean it but it seems like a crappy solution and one that creates problems with other characters for me.

Is there some more efficient way to clearing these characters without affecting the rest of the string ? for instance I am looking for a function that would strip % & # (and any other) from the string, but leave it intact otherwise. (preg_replace is not working for me)

In other words is there a way to accept the string and clean it without any potentially special characters getting converted so that I can strip them from the string.

EDIT: The query is coming in via GET, wasn't clear on that.
EDIT2: With urlecode or rawurl encode :
%acheron is converted to %ACheron (which could be cleaned I guess) but
^acheron is converted to %5Eacheron (thus making it almost impossible to clean it via a pattern)...

Please excuse the noobishness of my question
Thanks
Larry

Comment: Tried running urldecode() on it first?

Comment: I tried that its similar to rawurlencode - but If i use either it comes back as %ACheron but with the same function if the input is ^Acheron it is converted to %5Eacheron

Comment: What browser are you using that is converting %ac to ^A during form submission?

Comment: Firefox 10 - being stupid i have not tested it with anything else yet... will do... thanks

Comment: unfortunately same deal exactly with opera and safari

Comment: This is really unclear. Where does this string come from? If it's `%AC` in a URL, then it's correct that it's decoded into a different character. If you want to literally send the value "%ac..." in a URL, you need to URL encode that value so that the `%` is preserved literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $string = preg_replace("/(%|&|#)/", '', $string);

Something like this? This should work, if I understood your problem.

EDIT: Ok this is what you're looking for:

```
<?php
function myUrlEncode($string) {
    $entities = array('%21', '%2A', '%27', '%28', '%29', '%3B', '%3A', '%40', '%26', '%3D', '%2B', '%24', '%2C', '%2F', '%3F', '%25', '%23', '%5B', '%5D', '%5E');
    $replacements = array('!', '*', "'", "(", ")", ";", ":", "@", "&", "=", "+", "$", ",", "/", "?", "%", "#", "[", "]", "^");
    return str_replace($entities, $replacements, urlencode($string));
}


$search = myUrlEncode($_GET['id']);
$search = preg_replace("/(%|&|#)/", '', $search);

echo $search;
?>
```

Comment: That works, but watch out for the locals who down vote any usage of regular expressions for light text replacements.

Comment: Hi, thanks,but it wont work as this is input from a web form and by the time it gets to the script it has already encoded/decoded %ac (in this case) to the "not" sign

Comment: Please explain more. Add this check before anything happens? And also how does it look decoded, or what do you mean by decoded?

Comment: If i use urlencode or rawurlencode it comes back as %ACheron but with the same function if the input is ^Acheron it is converted to %5Eacheron

Comment: What to you input to get %ACheron? And can't you just put the preg_replace before you decode?

Comment: the input at the form : %acheron - the %ac part is converted to the "not" sign and with urlencode converted back to %AC but i cant use preg_replace as it could be any combination of letters

Comment: Do you want %5Eacheron to become ^Acheron?

Comment: When the browser sends "%acheron" it arrives as "¬heron"

Comment: What i want is acheron - with any character before it to become acheron, regardless of what characters are included in it.

Comment: use htmlentities() and then use the preg_match. EDIT instead of rawurldecode().

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion dear - but I tried that and %acheron is converted to notheron as htmlentites converts the ¬ to "not" the %ac seems to be converted to ¬ in the $_GET[]

Comment: Show some of the script. It'll be much easier to tell.
And can't you just remove the '%' from the $_GET[] before you do anything else with it?

Comment: There is a form which calls the script via get. The string is $thename which i  simply get via $thename = $_GET["name"]; at this stage before anythign else if the input at the form contains % $_GET[] already has the character (in this case ¬) and not a percentage sign, if i simply echo $thename before doing anything at all to the string its already ¬heron

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for trying to help me out i appreciate it allot

Comment: That's weird, did you code it yourself? Try to past the codes here: http://pastebin.com/ Remove the sensitive information, if there is any. There might be some problems in your form.

Comment: Its not an issue of the form cause even calling the script directly via url will get the same results. You can easily test this by making a simple script (http://pastebin.com/YR1NTw9c) call it anything you want and the call it via a url simply add ?id=%acheron and you will see what i mean

Comment: also add the following line $search = urlencode($search); and then test it by calling ?id=%acheron and ?id=^acheron and you will see what happens

Comment: Thanks for all the help alice i really really appreciate. The solution you present works, but will have to manually add some more parameters to deal with a few more characters then (like that darn ^). THANKS ALLOT FOR THE HELP. will get some sleep and work on it some more, its very confusing that there is no internal solution for this in php... again thanks alot dear.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like str_replace is what you are looking for.

For example:

```
$text = "%acheron";
$search = "%";
$replace = ""; //or whatever you want to replace it with
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
```

You can aswell make an array for `$search` and respectively an array for `$replace`

Comment: Unfortunately no that wont work cause by the time you get the string in the script it is converted. the %ac part of the string comes in as the "not" sign. thus i cant clean it that way :( perhaps i neglected to mention that this is input from a webbased form (GET)